# How to do client side dependent/partial validation in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a 2 check boxes  and  couple of text boxes associated with them .  If i check first check box then its associated text boxes must be validated and if i click second then second's associated text boxes must be validated .

I have a model with all the properties binded for this view. how to add a custom data annotation attribute when such situation exists?

Answer (score 0):

asp.net mvc 2 does not support contingent validation. However there is an open source library that incorporates data annotation to support contingent validation and provides you a way to hook it on the client side. I used it in my project and found it fairly good. You can find it [here](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/).